# How to include accented characters in Swift URL without percent encoding?

Tags: swift, string, url, urlcomponents

I am trying to make a web request to a URL that needs to keep accented characters instead of percent encoding them. E.g. `é` must NOT change to `e%CC%81`. I cannot change this.

These are the allowed characters that shouldn't be percent encoded: `AaÁáBbCcDdEeÉéFfGgHhIiÍíJjKkLlMmNnOoÓóÖöŐőPpQqRrSsTtUuÚúÜüŰűVvWwXxYyZz0123456789-`

> Here is an example of a url I need
>
> `https://helyesiras.mta.hu/helyesiras/default/suggest?q=hány%20éves`
>
> You can try this url in your web borwser to confirm its working. (The site is in Hungarian.) If you try the proper percent encoded version of this url (`https://helyesiras.mta.hu/helyesiras/default/suggest?q=ha%CC%81ny%20e%CC%81ves`) then the website will give an error. (Also in Hungarian.)

I have my custom encoder to get this URL string. However to make a web request I need to convert the `String` to `URL`.

I tried 2 ways:

1. `URL(string:)`

---

```
let urlStr = "https://helyesiras.mta.hu/helyesiras/default/suggest?q=hány%20éves"
var url = URL(string: urlStr)

// ERROR: Returns nil
```

---

---

2. `URLComponents` with `percentEncodedQueryItems`

---

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents()
urlComponents.scheme = "https"
urlComponents.host = "helyesiras.mta.hu"
urlComponents.path = "/helyesiras/default/suggest"
urlComponents.percentEncodedQueryItems = [           // ERROR: invalid characters in percent encoded query items
    URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: "hány%20éves")
]
let url = urlComponents.url
```

---

**Is it possible to create URLs without Foundation APIs checking its validity? Or can I create my own validation rules?**

Comment: you are using the wrong URLComponents property it should be `queryItems` not `percentEncodedQueryItems` => `urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: "hány éves")]` the resulting query part should be `"h%C3%A1ny%20%C3%A9ves"`

Comment: @LeoDabus I know, this is the problem, `urlComponents` is forcing percentEncoding when I don't want urlPercent encoding. I need the á to stay á and é to stay é.

Comment: You need to fix the server end. The percent encoding is correct

Comment: Regarding about if it works or not in Safari without percent encoding doesn’t mean anything

Answer (score 2):

Safari is percent-encoding the URL. You're just percent-encoding it differently (and in a way your server is rejecting). What Safari sends to the server is:

```
GET /helyesiras/default/suggest?q=h%C3%A1ny%20%C3%A9ves HTTP/1.1
```

You can check that using [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com). Your website is behaving correctly and does not appear to require unencoded URLs.

It is not valid to send unencoded URLs, and Safari doesn't. There's no way to do it with URLSession either. You'd have to connect to the socket directly and build your own HTTP stack, which is quite possible, but I don't think you want to do that.

As Leo notes, the correct way to do this is using:

```
URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: "hány éves")
```

Replacing the `%20` with the unencoded " " so that you don't double-encode the percent.

If you encode the string by hand, you'll find the same encoding:

```
print("hány éves".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed))
// Optional("h%C3%A1ny%20%C3%A9ves")
```

(But you should use URLComponents. `addingPercentEncoding` is extremely error-prone.)

The preferred UTF-8 encoding of `á` is as the unicode code point LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE (C3 A1). What you're encoding is LATIN SMALL LETTER A (61) followed by COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (CC 81). I suspect your server is not applying Unicode normalization rules. While that's unfortunate the fix is simple: use URLComponents, and you'll get the same correct behavior as Safari.